# ig4icd32.pdb not found in Visual Studio 15

Tags: c++, opengl, pdb-files

I am new to OpenGL development and when trying to debug my program with Visual Studio 15 I get the Message:

```
(Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig4icd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

I already activated the feature to synchronize pdb files with the Microsoft Server, but for this particular dll, it is not able to load them. I am using an Intel HD Graphics 3000 chip.

Comment: Afaik, it is not possible to debug into the intel driver (neither is it for any other driver vendor).

Comment: Yep, there are just no debugging symbols released for this driver.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info!

Comment: @BDL what does that mean? How am I supposed to run in debug mode then? should I roll back the intel driver?

Comment: @Joon.P: I'm not sure what you mean. You can build your code very well in debug mode. There are just no debugging symbols for the driver library which means you can't step into functions from this library. You can though debug your own code and any other library that has debug symbols.